# Using Jinja's "{% break %}" breaks my Javascript code. How can I solve this?

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

not a pun...

i'm fairly new to Javascript and Flask... this code here:

```
// searches for a name in the list of persons
function searchFName(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var fname = "";

    {% for i in range(persons|length) %}
        fname = {{ persons[i].fname|tojson }};

        if(userInput == fname)
        {
            alert(userInput + "found!");
        }
    {% endfor %}
}
```

works perfectly fine. It iterates over a list of persons, and check if their first names match with the one provided by the user... basically a search function.

However, I don't want to keep Jinja iterating over the list if the person has already been found.

So I tried adding `{% break %}` right here:

```
    if(userInput == fname)
    {
        alert(userInput + "found!");
        {% break %}
    }
```

and the function stops working and it gives me an error on the Console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

I know the question might be stupid and simple, but I have searched a lot and haven't found anyone with the same issue yet.

Any light on how to fix this, or work-arounds?

Thank you!

Comment: Is ```if(userInput == fname)
    {
        alert(userInput + "found!");
        {% break %}
    }``` meant to be a Jinja block of code or Javascript?

Comment: As you say "However, I don't want to keep Jinja iterating over the list if the person has already been found." when that is JS code.

Comment: @MatthewGaiser yep these are Javascript, the only Jinja code is `{% break %}`, should I not be mixing them together?

Comment: This isn’t the question you have asked, but I think it’s important to point out that inline JS is poor practice. There are a number of reasons for this, from [caching and code maintenance](https://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/) to [security](https://www.troyhunt.com/locking-down-your-website-scripts-with-csp-hashes-nonces-and-report-uri/). I’d recommend you give serious thought to separating out your JS so that it is static and not being generated by Jinja.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I don't want to keep Jinja iterating over the list if the person has already been found.

The template has no way of determining that. The template is rendered when the page is viewed, not when the function is called -- `{% break %}` will always break out of the loop and not generate the rest of the function. The syntax error arises because the `{% break %}` causes the closing brace of the `if` statement to be omitted.

Using templates to generate code is best avoided. A better approach here would be to make the entire array available to Javascript, then use a Javascript method to search the array:

```
function searchFName(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById("search").value;
    var fnames = {{ persons_fnames | tojson }};
    if (fnames.indexOf(userInput) !== -1) {
        alert(userInput + " found!");
   }
}
```

(Note that I have used `persons_fnames` here as a placeholder for a variable or expression which contains the value of `persons[i].fname` for each person. This list should probably be generated outside the template, so as to avoid placing too much logic in the template file.)